# Show that if $F,G, H$ are subspaces of $E$, then: $(F \cap G) + (F \cap H) \subseteq F + (G\cap H)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to show that if $F,G, H$ are subspaces of $E$, then: $(F \cap G) + (F \cap H) \subseteq F + (G\cap H)$.

$(F \cap G) + (F \cap H) = \left \{ w_{1} = u_{1} + v_{1}: u_{1} \in F \wedge u_{1} \in G \wedge v_{1} \in F \wedge v_{1} \in H \right \}$, so $w_{1} \in F \wedge w_{1} \in G \wedge w_{1} \in H$.

$F + (G\cap H) = \left \{ w_{2}: w_{2} \in F \wedge w_{2} = u_{2} + v_{2} : u_{2} \in G \wedge v_{2} \in H \right \}$, so $w_{2} \in F \wedge w_{2} \in G \wedge w_{2} \in H$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Let $w\in((F\cap G) + (F\cap H))$. Then it exists $w_{1}\in F\cap G$ and $w_{2}\in F\cap H$ such that $w = w_{1} + w_{2}$.

Since $F\cap G\subseteq F$ and $F\cap H\subseteq F$, we conclude that $w_{1}\in F$ and $w_{2}\in F$. Thus $w = w_{1} + w_{2}\in F$.

Once $0\in G\cap H$, it results that $w = w + 0 \in F + (G\cap H)$ and we are done.